# Simple for loop running infinitely

Tags: c, for-loop

I'm new to C and I need help with this simple exercise using `for`. I need to get a `char` and an `int` value from the user. Then I have to print that `char` as many times as the `int` entered before.

This is what I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char a;
    printf("Enter a character:");
    scanf(" %c", &a);
    int n;
    printf("Enter a number:");
    scanf(" %c", &n);
    printf("\n");

    int x;
    for(x=0; x < n; x++){
        printf(" %c", a);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My problem is that it makes an infinite loop in the `for`.

Please I need your help.

Thanks

Comment: Because you try to treat an `int` as if it was a `char`, you end up with 3 bytes of garbage plus 1 byte that matches the single digit you type (0x30 if you typed 0, 0x31 if you typed 1, etc, in the most common cases) in your loop limit.  If you do `printf("%d\n", n);` before the loop, you can see what the limit is in practice.  As the answer(s) diagnose, you should be using `%d` as the input format too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, `n` is an `int`, not a `char`. Thus, you need to use `%d` to read it. Using `%c` here will cause undefined behavior. According to *"C99 – ISO 9899-1999"*:

> **§7.19.6.2 The `fscanf` function**<sup>1</sup>
>
> [...] If this object does not have an appropriate type, or if the result of the conversion cannot be represented in the object, the behavior is undefined.

Change

```
scanf(" %c", &n);
```

to

```
scanf(" %d", &n);
```

Check out [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) for more info.

---

<sub>*1: The `scanf` function is equivalent to `fscanf` with the argument `stdin` interposed
before the arguments to `scanf`.*</sub>